# Visual Studio 2022: Just My Code Warning on first console app

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Installed Visual Studio and tried first C# console app (just Hello world). I tried switch to Release option before compiling and get warning:

> Just My Code Warning

> You are debugging a Release build of ConsoleApp1.dll. Using Just My Code with Release builds using compiler optimizations result in a degraded debugging exprience (e.g. breakpoints will not be hit).

It gives me options like Stop Debugging, Disable Just My Code and Continue, Continue Debugging, Continue Debugging (Don't Ask Again).

Just want to ask if this is normal behaviour? Why is this showing? What to choose?
**Will it somehow impact final exe file and future projects? Should I turn off Just my code feature?**

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can make its mark so that it can help more people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is normal.**

**First of all, please understand that Debug and Release in Visual Studio are two different configurations. They have the following main differences:**

Compilation methods are different: In Debug mode, the compiler will include debugging information in the generated executable file, but in Release mode, it will not. This reduces the size of the executable file and increases execution speed.

Different optimization levels: In Debug mode, the compiler will turn off various optimization options to facilitate debugging the program. In Release mode, the compiler will enable a variety of optimization options to improve program execution efficiency.

Preprocessor macro definitions are different: Some preprocessor macros (such as _DEBUG) are usually defined in Debug mode to facilitate debugging the program. In Release mode, these macros are usually not needed.

The runtime library is different: the runtime library in Debug mode is usually a multi-threaded debug version, while in Release mode it is usually a multi-threaded non-debug version. This is also to reduce the size of the executable file and increase execution speed.

So a warning will appear when you switch Debug to Release.

**What to choose?**

Stop debugging: This will stop the debugging session.

Disable "Just My Code and Continue": This will disable the "Just My Code" feature for the current debugging session and continue debugging.

Continue: This will continue debugging with the "Just My Code" feature enabled, knowing that you may not have the full debugging experience.

Continue debugging (don't ask again): This will continue debugging using the current settings without showing this warning again.

**As for whether you want to turn on or off "Just my code"**, it depends on your needs. As far as I am concerned, if I only debug my own code, I will turn on "Just my code". If I want to debug dependent libraries, I will turn it off. "Just my code". For details, please refer to: [Use "Only My Code" to debug only user code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022&source=recommendations)

Finally, it will not affect the final .exe file or any future projects you create. This warning is related to the debugging experience in Visual Studio and does not affect compiled output or the performance of your application.